# Javascript regex that matches dot as punctuation only, no numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, split, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to write a regex to split a sentence into words. My first thought was to split on spaces or punctuations then I realized that I don't want to split a number with decimals like "0.5" and I don't want to split a timestamp like "14:55:02". So, I tried to fix my problem with negative lookahead and negative lookbehind, but I'm not able to put them together... And lookbehind doesn't seem to be supported in javascript.

My best try so far:

```
var query = "I've been 0.5 hit at 21:05. I'm okay.";
var delimiter = /[\s\.,:;?!+=\/\\]+(?![0-9])/g;

if(delimiter.test(query)){

    var words = query.split(delimiter);
    console.log(words);

    // ["I've", "been 0.5", "hit", "at 21:05", "I'm", "okay", ""]
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/5y8tzyx1/2/)**

So basically, I need a regex that will split my query on `[\s\.,:;?!+=\/\\]+` but don't split if `[\.,:/]` is wrapped by numbers. Please help!

Comment: Are the 'regular' `.` and `:` always followed by a space, as in your one single example?

Comment: It's not always followed by a space, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on it:

```
[\s,;?!+=/\\]+|[.:](?!\d)\s*
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tD6nD2/1)
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xs5g3ynz/)

Basically I've split the two cases, and made the lookahead only apply after `.` or `:`.

And yes, JS doesn't support lookbehinds, unfortunately.

For the more troublesome `I love pizza.2 more pizzas please!` case, you'd need to switch to matching instead of splitting:

```
(?:\d[.:]\d|[^\s.:,;?!+=/\\])+
```

This won't count a `.` or `:` as a separator if it's between two digits.

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tD6nD2/2)

And in JS:

```js
var query = "I've been 0.5 hit at 21:05. I'm okay. I love pizza.2 more pizzas please!" ;
var re = /(?:\d[.:]\d|[^\s.:,;?!+=\/\\])+/g;
var words = [];
var match;

while (match = re.exec(query))
    words.push(match[0]);
        
for (i in words)
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += words[i] + "<br>";
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: It works, but why escape `?`, `!`, `+` and `/` inside a character class?

Comment: @Jongware You're right, I just mindlessly copy/pasted this from the question and didn't pay enough attention.

Comment: That's a really good solution, but if your second sentence start by a number like `I love pizza.2 more pizzas please!`, it doesn't work. Do you think of an improvement for this? Still, that's a weird sentence...

Comment: That's such a nice solution! I'm impressed! Thank you so much!